# Unknown authority self-signed certificate issue in kuberenets docker private registry

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, docker-registry

I'm setting up a kubernetes (microk8s) cluster with a private docker registry.

I'm following the tutorial at this link https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-private-docker-registry-kubernetes/

When generating the self-signed certificate, I used the following command (slightly different from that used in the tutorial to allow reference to the server's IP instead of a DNS name):

```
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout \
     /opt/certs/registry.key -x509 -days 365 \
    -subj "/CN=<SERVERIP>" \
    -addext "subjectAltName = IP:<SERVERIP>" \
    -out /opt/certs/registry.crt
```

This is the Registry Deployment, as described in the article:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: private-repository-k8s
  labels:
    app: private-repository-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: private-repository-k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: private-repository-k8s
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: certs-vol
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/certs
          type: Directory
      - name: registry-vol
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/registry
          type: Directory

      containers:
        - image: registry:2
          name: private-repository-k8s
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: "/certs/registry.crt"
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
            value: "/certs/registry.key"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: certs-vol
            mountPath: /certs
          - name: registry-vol
            mountPath: /var/lib/registry
```

[edit] I also add the NodePort descriptor for the repository

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: private-repository-k8s
  name: private-repository-k8s
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    nodePort: 31320
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: private-repository-k8s
  type: NodePort
```

Then, I apply the Deployment of my application component

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp-hello-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp-hello-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: "<SERVERIP>:31320/myapp/hello:0.1.0"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: myapp-hello
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
            name: http
```

When I apply this, I get the following error when kubernetes tries to pull the image:

```
Failed to pull image "<SERVERIP>:31320/myapp/hello:0.1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<SERVERIP>:31320/myapp/hello:0.1.0": failed to resolve reference "<SERVERIP>:31320/myapp/hello:0.1.0": failed to do request: Head "https://<SERVERIP>:31320/v2/myapp/hello/manifests/0.1.0": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The image is on the docker registry with the correct tag "SERVERIP:31320/myapp/hello:0.1.0"

Any idea of what might be the problem? Please take into account that I'm no ssl or x509 expert

Thanks

Comment: You need to add the CA as a trusted CA on the nodes in your kubernetes cluster. There may also be methods to trust the certificate by your CRI.

Comment: Could you please add some more information on how to practically add the CA as a trusted CA on the nodes in the k8s cluster?

Comment: I can't, because I don't know what kind of nodes you are running, or what CRI you are using. This is either a Linux OS question, or a question about your specific CRI, depending on where you want to fix it.

Comment: @chrx, have you found any solution for this? I m alos facing same issue

Comment: not yet, unfortunately. for the moment I'm temporarily using a public externa docker registry (docker hub), waiting to find a solution for this issue...

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We're still using the public docker registry (docker hub).